# Android tethering web server

Tags: android, wifi, tethering

I am looking for a method to display a webpage when somebody connects to my hotspot

.Is there a way I could implement this?

Comment: Look into [captive portals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). You want to use a turnkey solution if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the Android access restrictions are, but assuming your app has the network read / write / bind permissions, the simplest thing to do is simple embed Jetty and get it to start a server on the specified port, example are : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

EDIT: Upon further reading of your question that's just the start, you will need to block all other network traffic until the client has accepted the captive portal above.

Hope I helped

md_5